# How to evaluate strings as expressions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, parsing, matrix, eval

Nube here trying to learn R..
I have a dataframe and am trying to programmatically construct a matrix from some columns.  Having a heck of a time with the syntax.

Here is the input data

```
XV= 0.5 0.5 1 1.5 3.5 5.5 7 9 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 

YV= 5 10 25 15 15 25 25 45 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 

type= 1BP2 2B 1BP2 2BP 1BP2 1BP2 1BP2 1BP2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Here is the df
[image: dataframe]

I do not know ahead of time how many rows, but the ZL terms will have the same number as the XL variable, and there will be as many columns of ZL variables as there are rows of YL variable.  This all leads to a simple 2D interpolation algorithm and I am trying to build the lookup matrix.

Code goes like this

```
    z <- curvsx(XV,YV,type,lookupfile)

in curvsx...

    curvsx <- function(xi,yi,type,dfname) {

    df<-read.csv(dfname)

    xl<-eval(parse(text=(paste("na.omit(df$XL",TYPE,")",sep=""))))

    Nxl<-length(na.omit(xl))

    yl<-eval(parse(text=(paste("na.omit(df$YL",TYPE,")",sep=""))))

    Nyl<-length(na.omit(yl))
```

for TYPE="1BP2" above code produces

```
    TYPE
     "1BP2"

    Nxl
     7

    Nyl
     3

    xl
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7

    attr(,"na.action")


    attr(,"class")
     "omit"

    yl
    10 20 30

    attr(,"na.action")
    4 5 6 7 8

    attr(,"class")
    "omit"   

    #this works but is clunky... (print statements to aid debug)
    for (i in 1:Nyl) {

     zl<-eval(parse(text=(paste("na.omit(df$ZL",i,TYPE,")",sep=""))))

     if(i==1) {zo<-matrix(zl,nrow=Nxl,byrow=FALSE)}

     else {zo<-matrix(c(zo,zl),nrow=Nxl,byrow=FALSE)}

     print(zo)

    }
    # produces...

         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]  100  200  300
    [2,]  200  300  400
    [3,]  300  600 1000
    [4,]  400  900 1600
    [5,]  500 1200 2200
    [6,]  600 1500 2800
    [7,]  700 1800 3400
```

this was my elegant attempt at doing it in 1 line, but does not work...

```
    zo=matrix(c(eval(parse(text=(paste("na.omit(df$ZL",i=1:Nyl,TYPE,")",sep=""))))),ncol=Nyl,byrow=FALSE)
    # results in...

    > zo 
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]  300 1600 3400
    [2,]  400 2200  300
    [3,] 1000 2800  400
```

when I try to debug 1 liner by looking at it in pieces...

```
    paste("na.omit(df$ZL",i=1:Nyl,TYPE,")",sep="")

    # produces

   "na.omit(df$ZL11BP2)" "na.omit(df$ZL21BP2)" "na.omit(df$ZL31BP2)"

    parse(text=(paste("na.omit(df$ZL",i=1:Nyl,TYPE,")",sep="")))

    # produces

    expression(na.omit(df$ZL11BP2), na.omit(df$ZL21BP2), 
    na.omit(df$ZL31BP2))    

    # but things seem to go south on

    c(eval(parse(text=(paste("na.omit(df$ZL",i=1:Nyl,TYPE,")",sep="")))))

    #which produces

    300  400 1000 1600 2200 2800 3400 

    # what I was hoping for, I thought I was executing this

    c(na.omit(df$ZL11BP2), na.omit(df$ZL21BP2), na.omit(df$ZL31BP2))

    # which produces what I want...

    100  200  300  400  500  600  700  200  300  600  900 1200 1500 1800  300  400 1000 1600 2200 2800 3400
```

What am I missing or not understanding

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Could you please edit your question and insert the desired output before your attempts?

Comment: thx nicola, I reread my post and even I could not understand it!  added some details that were missing. At  the very bottom is the problem, I think i should be combining 3 vectors which I want to turn into a matrix, but adding the c() around the built up expression does not go as I expected...

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use `tidyr` to pivot the data longer and split the column names into `Variable`, `MainType`, and `SubType`.

Then it becomes easy to filter them.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), values_to = "Value") %>%
  separate(name,into = c("Variable","Type"), sep = 2) %>%
  mutate(MainType = str_extract(Type,"[0-9]BP?[0-9]*"),
         SubType = str_remove(Type,MainType),
         SubType = if_else(SubType == "", NA_character_, SubType)) 
data
## A tibble: 88 x 5
#   Variable Type  Value MainType SubType
#   <chr>    <chr> <int> <chr>    <chr>  
# 1 XL       1B        1 1B       NA     
# 2 YL       1B       10 1B       NA     
# 3 ZL       11B     100 1B       1      
# 4 ZL       21B     200 1B       2      
# 5 ZL       31B     300 1B       3      
# 6 ZL       41B     400 1B       4      
# 7 XL       1BP2      1 1BP2     NA     
# 8 YL       1BP2     10 1BP2     NA     
# 9 ZL       11BP2   100 1BP2     1      
#10 ZL       21BP2   200 1BP2     2      
## … with 78 more rows
```

Then it's relatively easy to write a function that creates the matrices:

```
library(purrr)
mytype <- "1BP2"
data %>%
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(Value) & MainType == mytype)  %>%
  split(.,.$Variable) %>% 
  map(~.x %>%
        pivot_wider(id_cols = c("Row","SubType"),
                    names_from = SubType,
                    values_from = Value) %>%
        {as.matrix(.[,-1])}
      )
$XL
     1
[1,] 1
[2,] 2
[3,] 3
[4,] 4
[5,] 5
[6,] 6
[7,] 7
$YL
      1
[1,] 10
[2,] 20
[3,] 30
$ZL
       1    2    3
[1,] 100  200  300
[2,] 200  300  400
[3,] 300  600 1000
[4,] 400  900 1600
[5,] 500 1200 2200
[6,] 600 1500 2800
[7,] 700 1800 3400
```

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(XL1B = 1:8, YL1B = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), ZL11B = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L), ZL21B = c(200L, 300L, 600L, 900L, 1200L, 1500L, 1800L, 
2100L), ZL31B = c(300L, 400L, 1000L, 1600L, 2200L, 2800L, 3400L, 
4000L), ZL41B = c(400L, 500L, 1700L, 2900L, 4100L, 5300L, 6500L, 
7700L), XL1BP2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, NA), YL1BP2 = c(10L, 
20L, 30L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ZL11BP2 = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 
400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, NA), ZL21BP2 = c(200L, 300L, 600L, 900L, 
1200L, 1500L, 1800L, NA), ZL31BP2 = c(300L, 400L, 1000L, 1600L, 
2200L, 2800L, 3400L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thanks Ian.  I need to study this a little... lots of stuff in here that is new to me!